# New Yorker's Possessive of Title in Quote Marks

Tags: punctuation

The New Yorker does possessive of titles in quotes like this (even if it's a movie title, they use quotes):

“Saturday Night Live” ’s cast

“Jeopardy!” ’s host Alex Trebek

“What’s Going On?” ’s lyrics

They use a space after the ending quote mark and then follow it with an apostrophe plus "s," as shown in the three examples above.

My question is, if we have a title that already ends in "s" inside the quotes, would we still, per New Yorker style, add the apostrophe plus "s" after "The Sopranos" below (as shown)?

“The Sopranos” ’s David Chase...

Comment: The only one who can answer that is *The New Yorker*. But what would they do with a title like *Waitin’* ? Would it be *“Waitin’ ” ’s*?

Comment: *The New Yorker* does it's own thing.  You'd have to ask them what they'd do in that specific case.

Comment: Having ceased using underling for titles, the rest of the world now uses italics. Apparently they didn't get the memo and don't use SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about one particular style rather than standard usage, and should be checked with the authors of the relevant style guide.

Comment: @Mazura Great point. Any way to invite them?

Comment: Oh, New Yorker. Never change.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The specifics of different styles and style guide suggestions/rules is historically very much on topic at ELU.

Comment: @Mitch In the Meta question [Is MLA on topic?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/is-mla-on-topic/4328#4328), Tim Lymington disagrees: "There seems to be a general consensus that questions ... which ask about how to fit your text within MLA (or other stylebooks) are off-topic, since both 'what MLA mandates' and 'the way your professor prefers papers set out' are valuable advice to the student, but cannot be classified as 'English Language & Usage'." See also John Lawler's advice there.

Comment: What _should_ be done with punctuation is off-topic. What a particular style suggests and how it applies to a particular phrase certainly is. Serial comma, diaeresis, how to spell Rumanian [sic] are style choices that are certainly covered to excess here. (of course any gen ref thing like 'what _does_ MLA say to do?'  or opinion thing 'what your prof says' is off topic for those reasons)

Answer (score 5):

Your guess is entirely correct.

Google finds the quote

> several of “The Sopranos” ’s directors

[here](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2010/09/20/jersey-boys) on “The New Yorker” ’s website.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mazura commented,

> Having ceased using underling for titles, the rest of the world now uses italics.

You need to note that just because The New Yorker used a certain type of style doesn't necessarily mean it applies to other publishers or authors.

Other Stack Exchange sites related with moves and TV shows, [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions) and [Movies & TV SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions) use *italic* for *name of works* as indicated in the question below:

[Are there official style rules for names of works?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/are-there-official-style-rules-for-names-of-works)

Regarding your question, the answer is you can follow your style guide or manual. There could be three popular choices:

> *The Sopranos*’ David Chase...
>
> The Sopranos’ David Chase...
>
> “The Sopranos” ’s David Chase...

Comment: Had to share. I emailed the Associated Press. They replied and said to handle those examples like this: "Saturday Night Live's" cast

"Jeopardy!'s"  host Alex Trebek

"What’s Going On?'s" lyrics